# What is the meaning of (n:ns) in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, syntax

In the first chapter of the book, Programming in Haskell, it has the following function definition:

```
summ [] = 0
summ (n:ns) = n + summ ns
```

What is the meaning of `(n:ns)`, I guess from the function `ns` is a list and `n` is the first element of the original list, but what does the `(n:ns)` notation actually tell Haskell? What part of the notation makes it clear what happens in the function?

Comment: Is that really not explained in the same chapter?

Comment: In that contest `n:ns` is a list pattern. The book should explain that defining `summ (n:ns) = ...` means "if the input is a list starting with head element `n` and continuing with a tail sublist `ns` then the result of `summ` is defined as ...".

Comment: @chepner so far as I can see, no!

Comment: @chi Could you write that up into an answer? I'm happy to accept it, even though I realise it's basic. I basically understand that `n` is the first element of the list and `ns` is the rest, but I'm just wondering how Haskell figures that out? Is it the syntax? Is it the `s` after the `n`? Why do you have to put it into brackets?

Comment: The names are not special, you can use `(xyz : abc)` if you want. The `:` separates head and tail. Parentheses are needed since `f n:ns` would mean `(f n) : ns` instead -- function application has top priority.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sequence `(n:ns)` is a shorthand for head - tail. Quite literally, the first value, the head, is called `n` and the remained are the other, potentially plural, `n`s, which is why it is called `ns`.

Haskell has pattern matching. So, if I say `(n:ns) = [1,2,3]` then Haskell will pattern match `n` to `1`, and `ns` to match `[2,3]`. Effectively, `n:ns` salami slices the first value off the front of the list.

The algorithm for calculating the sum of a list in Haskell is recursive. If the list is empty, `[ ]`, then zero is returned. Otherwise, we slice off the first value from the list, `n`, and add it to the result.

Haskell has a REPL, called ghci, and using this is fundamental to getting the hang of the language.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot, does that mean a list can be sliced up multiple ways, or can it only have a head and a tail? I also take it that `ns` is just convention and could be anything?

Comment: @Connor `ns` is indeed just a convention. You can write `head:tail` or `foo:bar` or anything you want. The real meaningful thing is the colon.  The (single) colon is an operator (technically, a "constructor") that makes a list out of a head and a tail, and the same symbol slices a list into a head and a tail. It is the only way to slice a list.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. What do the parentheses mean? Are they to indicate the two variables aren't separate?

Comment: Yes  like most other parentheses, they group things that otherwise would be separate.

Answer (score 1):

`:` builds lists.

```
Prelude> :t (:)
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

It takes an element of type `a`, and a list of the same type elements. That list may be either empty (`[]`) or some element on the front of some other list. The definition of lists this way allows for lists of any number of elements.

`[1, 2, 3, 4]` is just a nice shorthand for `1 : 2 : 3 : 4 : []`.

The same syntax is used for destructuring lists. The pattern `n:ns` binds `n` to the head and `ns` to the tail of a list. Nothing stops you from using the pattern `n:n':ns` to bind `n` to the first element, `n'` to the second element, and `ns` to *the rest*.

Consider the usefulness of this in finding a list of every other element of a list. *The `_` pattern is used for a portion of the pattern we don't actually need to name.*

```
everyOther :: [a] -> [a]
everyOther []       = []
everyOther (n:[])   = [n]
everyOther (n:_:ns) = n : everyOther ns
```

Comment: What do the parentheses mean? Are they to indicate the two variables aren't separate?

Comment: Without the parentheses `everyOther n:ns = ...` would parse as `(everyOther n) : ns = ...` which would be a syntax error.